# Modify msrtcsip-userenabled Active Directory Attribute

Tags: powershell, active-directory, skype, lync, office-communicator

I need to modify the msrtcsip-userenabled attribute from True to False for a list of users. So far here's what I have:

To gather the list of users:

```
Get-Aduser -Filter * -Properties homeDirectory | Where-Object {$_.homeDirectory -Like "\\SERVERNAME*"} | Select-Object SamAccountName
```

I need to modify each of the users, I know that I'll need to use `set-aduser`.
Either importing the results into the next part of the script or exporting to CSV would work.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `Set-Aduser` like

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties homeDirectory | Where-Object {$_.homeDirectory -Like "\\SERVERNAME*"} | Set-ADUser -Clear 'msrtcsip-userenabled'
```

to clear the value.

Or you could overwrite the value to something new, like this:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties homeDirectory | Where-Object {$_.homeDirectory -Like "\\SERVERNAME*"} | Set-ADUser -Replace @{'msrtcsip-userenabled' = 'new value'}
```

no need to export to a CSV file (unless you need to).

Comment: The overwrite value option looks like it will work. What would I need to do if I wanted to edit that list before making the change? CSV, then some sort of pause, edit the file and then resume?

Comment: Had to slightly adjust it, but it's working now, using: 'code' Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties homeDirectory | Where-Object {$_.homeDirectory -Like "\\Servername*"} | Set-ADUser -Replace @{'msRTCSIP-UserEnabled' = $false}

Comment: That's strange though. When I tested with `-Replace` and setting it to `$false` the value was `"FALSE"` when checking it with AD Users and Computers mmc snap-in. however glad it works for you.